# My final explosion render looks completely different from my preview render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I made a post about this, but it didn't save. Anyways I've been trying to render an explosion in cycles and it comes out looking completely different, here are some pictures of the explosions and render settings.  Let me know if anything else is needed.  [image: Preview render][[image: Final Render][2]]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In the sampling pane the [render] and [viewport] have different values.  So do you think they could easily look different?  I am not making any statement such as [better].  Perhaps it would be an experiment to set them to the same value.   Perhaps you accidentally deleted the original of this post.

Comment: Wouldd the light paths have anything to do with it? Or volumes?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger ^